# Flex RemoteObject get size of request/response

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, remoteobject

As title says for some purpose I need to get the size of request/response from a RemoteObject,  tracking the calls with the Network Monitor I can see the request/response size, but I can't find it in the framework..

I tried to look into every variables/method of the remoteobject itself and the resultevent/faultevent without luck...

any guess?

I cannot think that there is no implementation for such a thing...

Comment: Why do you need this value from code?  Why won't the network monitor stats serve your purposes?

Comment: because I need to display on my application how big is the data trasmitted and received.... like downloaded: xx MB - uploaded: yy MB

Comment: What do you need the size of?  The actual requests, or the data contained in the request?

Comment: I would guess it's the response that's of interest.  To display a progress bar, this would indeed be quite helpful; I've been looking for something like this myself.

Comment: @Flextras, one or another is not a problem.. I need the size in bytes of the request or the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex just makes a request and waits a result.
Everything in between is executed by an other language that does not communicate to flex until its "return".

So what I was looking for is impossible and we can only addEventListener on Start/Fault/Result event....

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you find the size of your object on your server side and access the same as a RO from flex.That should solve d problem I guess.

Comment: no, it solve the problem of knowing the size of the object (?) but I could not know the progress of datas received by the client... I want a simple progress bar during the dowload... I think it's not possible..